# huggingface transformers bert model without classification layer

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I want to do a joint-embedding from vgg16 and `bert` for classification.

The thing with `huggingface transformers bert` is that it has the classification layer which has `num_labels` dimension.

But, I want the output from `BertPooler` (768 dimensions) which I will use as a text-embedding for an extended model.

```
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification

model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
```

This gives the following model:

```
BertForSequenceClassification(
...
...
        (11): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
      )
    )
    (pooler): BertPooler(
      (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (activation): Tanh()
    )
  )
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
  (classifier): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2, bias=True)
)
```

How can I get rid of the `classifier` layer?

Comment: With joint embedding, are you going to concatenate the vgg16 and bert vectors and use for training?

Comment: yes, something similar. Will have to experiment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from transformers import BertModel
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
```

Output

```
(11): BertLayer(
        (attention): BertAttention(
          (self): BertSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): BertSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
        )
        (output): BertOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (pooler): BertPooler(
    (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
    (activation): Tanh()
  )
)
```

Checkout the BertModel definition [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L865).